# Restructure MySQL table to create one column per id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have one MySQL table with the following structure:

```
+-------------+-------+-----------+
|  timestamp  | value | sensor_id |
+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

Let's say as an example that there are three possible sensors_ids: `id1`,`id2` and `id3`.
I would like to perform a query to output the data in the following format:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  timestamp  | value_id1 | value_id2 | value_id3 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

It is straightforward to extract data from one ID only but I'm struggling to combine the 3 of them.

```
SELECT timestamp,
       value AS 'value_id1'
FROM table
WHERE sensor_id='id1'
```

**EDIT** for clarifications:
(`timestamp`,`sensor_id`) is unique over the table

Comment: Is `(timestamp, sensor_id)` unique over the table?

Comment: @Akina yes it is

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    timestamp,
    max(case when sensor_id = 'id1' then value end) value_id1,
    max(case when sensor_id = 'id2' then value end) value_id2,
    max(case when sensor_id = 'id3' then value end) value_id3
from mytable
group by timestamp
```